# MYSQL - Group By / Order By not working

Tags: mysql

I have the following data inside a table:

```
id   person_id   item_id  price 
1    1           1        10
2    1           1        20 
3    1           3        50
```

Now what I want to do is group by the item ID, select the id that has the highest value and take the price.

E.g. the sum would be: (20 + 50) and ignore the 10.

I am using the following:

```
SELECT SUM(`price`)
FROM
  (SELECT id, person_id, item_id, price
   FROM `table` tbl 
   INNER JOIN person p USING (person_id)
   WHERE p.person_id = 1
   ORDER BY id DESC) x 
GROUP BY item_id
```

However, this query is still adding (10 + 20 + 50), which is obviously not what I need to have.

Any ideas to where I am going wrong?

Comment: @lvar - No, since I want to get all the items that relate to this person

Comment: @RyanVincent If I output the `(SELECT id..`)` it shows all 3 values

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you are trying to achieve. First you need grouping in a subquery and not in outer query. In outer query you need only sum:

```
SELECT SUM(`price`)
FROM
  (SELECT MAX(price) as price
   FROM `table` tbl 
   INNER JOIN person p USING (person_id)
   WHERE p.person_id = 1
   GROUP BY item_id) x
```

Comment: what `INNER JOIN person p` stands for?

Comment: @Alex, I just copied the query from the question. May be `price` or `itemid` columns are from `person` table I don't know.

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri It shouldn't be returning the max price, it should work off the MAX(id) since this is the most current value. The MAX(price) is not always right. My problem is that the price could be 1000 THEN the next day could be 900.. I just want to take the 900 as it's the most up to date

Comment: @Phorce, ok, the question was confusing. I will edit if you tell which column comes from which table.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40803/5

```
SELECT SUM(t1.price) 
FROM tbl t1
LEFT JOIN tbl t2
ON t1.person_id= t2.person_id
  AND t1.item_id = t2.item_id
  AND t1.id<t2.id
WHERE t1.person_id = 1
  AND t2.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the only requirement you have. If so, try this.

`SELECT SUM(price)
FROM
 (SELECT MAX(price)
  FROM table
  WHERE person_id = 1
  GROUP BY item_id)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you don't need the *person* table, because the other table already contains the *person_id*. So i removed it from the examples.

Your query returns a sum of prices for each item.
If you replace `SELECT SUM(price)` with `SELECT item_id, SUM(price)` you wil get

```sql
item_id   SUM(`price`)
1         30
3         50
```

But that is not what you want. Neither is it what you wrote in the question " (10 + 20 + 50)".

Now replacing the first line with `SELECT id, item_id, SUM(price)` you will get one row for each item with the highest *id*.

```sql
id   item_id   price
2    1         20
3    3         50
```

This works because of the "**undocumented feature**" of MySQL, wich allows you to select columns that are not listed in the `GROUP BY` clause and get the first row from the subselect each group (each item in this case).

Now you only need to sum the *price* column in an additional outer select

```sql
SELECT SUM(price)
FROM (
    SELECT id, item_id ,price
    FROM (
        SELECT id, person_id, item_id, price
        FROM `table` tbl 
        WHERE tbl.person_id = 1
        ORDER BY id DESC ) x 
    GROUP BY item_id 
) y
```

However i do **not** recomend to use that "feature". While it still works on MySQL 5.6, you never know if that will work with newer versions. It already doesn't work on MariaDB.

Instead you can determite the `MAX(id)` for each item in an subselect, select only the rows with the determined ids and get the summed price of them.

```sql
SELECT SUM(`price`)
FROM `table` tbl
WHERE tbl.id IN (
    SELECT MAX(tbl2.id)
    FROM `table` tbl2
    WHERE tbl2.person_id = 1
    GROUP BY tbl2.item_id
)
```

Another solution (wich internaly does the same) is

```sql
SELECT SUM(`price`)
FROM `table` tbl
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(tbl2.id) as id
    FROM `table` tbl2
    WHERE tbl2.person_id = 1
    GROUP BY tbl2.item_id
) x ON x.id = tbl.id
```

Alex's solution also works fine, if the groups (number of rows per person and item) are rather small.

Answer (score 0):

You have used group by in main query, but it is on subquery like

```
SELECT  id, person_id, item_id, SUM(`price`) FROM   (  SELECT MAX(price)   FROM `table` tbl  WHERE p.person_id = 1 GROUP BY item_id  ) AS x
```